# Geting fully qualified path in a nodejs traceback?

Tags: node.js, path, console.log, backtrace

A nodejs (v8?) backtrace can look like this:

```
...
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:95:17)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
```

Inside a javascript program that produces this, how can I most definitively figure out the fully-qualified path given in parenthesis? For example, above we have *events.js* or *readline.js*.

Looking at the code for [nodejs's lib/module.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js) I see there is a *_findPath()* function. So I could try:

```
x = 'events.js' // See traceback above
m = require('module');
m._findPath(x, m.globalPaths)
```

But I am just guessing here. Is there a better way? Thoughts on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no other suggestions as indicated above, I use:

`x = 'events.js';
m = require('module');
m._findPath(x, m.globalPaths)`